# Can't run the 'sudo supervisorctl reload' command in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, supervisord

i very new with ubuntu and i was try to using the supervisor to manage my web application follow by this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=goToXTC96Co&t=2068s, but after i run the command `sudo supervisorctl reload`, it error like below.

```
  File "/usr/bin/supervisorctl", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3088, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3072, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3101, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 574, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 892, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 778, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'supervisor==3.3.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

And after i change some configuration in `/usr/bin/supervisorctl` file, change from `#!/usr/bin/python` to `#!/usr/bin/python2` and after i run command `sudo supervisorctl reload` again, i still get the error like this.

```
error: <class 'socket.error'>, [Errno 2] No such file or directory: file: /usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py line: 228
```

so please, how can i solve the ploblem.

Comment: It seems that the version of supervision you installed is old: try to get the latest via pip (`pip install supervisor`). The latest uses Python3 so the trick you did to make it use Python2 isn't needed.

Comment: @DPD- thank you for response, i just do `pip install supervisor` and remove 2 in `#!/usr/bin/python2` to `#!/usr/bin/python` and run the `sudo supervisorctl reload` command i still got the same error as the first one, so how can do?

Comment: Are you using bionic (18.04)? If it's so the supervisor version on pip is newer (4.2.0) than that required by NGINX (3.3.1), so you can try install it from `universe`: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/supervisor